# How do I compare two array's values?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have 2 arrays one retrieved from a database (saved results) and the other from an xml (new results)

```
$fromDB = array('123','124','524','15','616');
$fromXML = array('123','124','524','15','818');
```

I want to compare those two and see which values are old (fromDB) and which are new (fromXML) so to insert the old value in a different table.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [array_diff()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function